# Weird behavior with Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Why are the tabs not working as properly in rails? Is Bootstrap's JavaScript file not loading properly or am I doing something wrong? I have a tab panel that basically have two contents. One for questions and the other for blog posts. Whenever I refresh the page, the blog post's inner HTML gets mixed with the question's panel as if the Bootstap's script never actually 'loaded'.

To to exemplify my question, here is an image of when I refresh the page:

[image]

And here's an image for when I click on one of the tabs. (The script loads, and separates the contents the way I wanted.)

**Question's tab:**

[image]

**Blog post's tab:**

[image]

Application.js code:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Panel code:

```
      <div class="well">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li role="presentation"><a class="none white" href="#questions" aria-controls="questions" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Questions</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a class="none white" href="#posts" aria-controls="posts" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Blog posts</a></li>
        </ul>   

          <div class="tab-content">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="questions">
            <br>
                <% @user.questions.each do |question| %>
                    <%= link_to question.title, question_path(question), :class => "ques" %>
                    <p class="pull-right">
                        <%= question.user.username %>
                    </p>
                    <hr/>
                <% end %>
            </div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="posts">
            <br>
                <p><a href="#" class="ques">test blog post 123 123</a></p>
                <p><a href="#" class="ques">test blog post 123 123</a></p>
                <p><a href="#" class="ques">test blog post 123 123</a></p>
                <p><a href="#" class="ques">test blog post 123 123</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I would start by getting rid of the `<br>` and `<hr>` tags - use CSS instead.

Comment: Have you checked the log to see if Bootstrap is loading? It would be impossible for us to check this here to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had the active class mistakenly added on both panels. So by removing the second class, everything got fixed.

Comment: I can't. I need to wait for two days.